# issue when running cmder.exe from a java application

Tags: java, cmder

I'm trying to run cmder.exe from a java application. I'm using the java ProcessBuilder class and it works great with cmd.exe, but never with cmder.exe.

This is my code:

```
    command =    "cd C:\\Users\\fxxx\\Documents\\plt 3.0\\git\\xxx-estatic";
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PLT 3.0\\abc\\cmder_mini\\cmder.exe", "/start", command);
```

I want to open the cmder command prompt and run a "cd" command. Cmder.exe is actually launched, but I get the "file name, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect" error message and my command (cd...) is never executed.

Again, things work perfectly if I use cmd.exe.

Does someone know how to effectively run cmder.exe from a java application?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not from `...\\plt 3.0\\...` that space? If you run manual it work?

Comment: does cmder takes commands as arguments? or is it input given after cmder started ?

Comment: @raul1ro, yes it works when I run it manually and also on cmd.exe.

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty, I really do not know how to run cmder.exe via ProcessBuilder. Surely there are some tricks that I need to learn. I want to use cmder because the user interface is better than the black and white cmd.exe. Is there a way to add some color to cmd.exe?

Answer (score 0):

RTFM!

Assuming that you use [that cmder.exe](http://cmder.net/), the doc states:

> Cmder.exe  Command Line Arguments

> ```
> Argument                Description
> /C [user_root_path]     Individual user Cmder root folder. Example: %userprofile%\cmder_config
> /SINGLE                 Start Cmder is single mode.
> /START [start_path]     Folder path to start in.
> /TASK [task_name]       Task to start after launch.
> ```

That means that your code should be:

```
path =    "cd C:\\Users\\fxxx\\Documents\\plt 3.0\\git\\xxx-estatic";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\PLT 3.0\\abc\\cmder_mini\\cmder.exe", "/start", path);
```

Comment: hi, that is what I am doing. I can get cmder to open a command prompt, but, differently from cmd.exe, it will not run anything sent from the java program. it seems I can only input commands manually on cmder.exe.